# Unable to download Google Allo from Google Play Store - Pre-register/Unregister

Tags: applications, google-play-store, google, google-apps

So [Google Allo](https://allo.google.com/) was officially released just a few days ago as per this [Google Blog](https://googleblog.blogspot.com/2016/09/google-allo-smarter-messaging-app.html):

> **Today**, we’re releasing Google Allo, a new smart messaging app **for Android and iOS** that helps you say more and do more right in your chats.

*Today* being Sept. 20, 2016 as per the blog's post date, while in our country, it's already Sept. 22nd.

I followed the link up to it's [Google Play Store page](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.fireball&hl=en), but still only see it as *Coming Soon* and the <kbd>Pre-register</kbd>/<kbd>Unregister</kbd> button.

Is this an expected delay since it is still being *deployed*? Or was there an unexpected delay in the release or is it just that my phone is not compatible with it?

I'm using Asus Zenfone 2 ZE551ML with Android L and the Google Play Services is up-to-date. However, there is the behavior of Google Play Store to not show the app to non-compatible (*blacklisted*) devices for searches, and a label of

> Device not compatible

if you were still able to find the page, pretty much rules out the device compatibility issue.

Comment: As per [Apk mirror](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/allo-by-google/allo-by-google-1-0-006_rc18-release/#downloads) there are 16 variants bringing it to various device configurations. Wondering if the right device configuration is not available (goof up?) In your country. You could try installing x86 versions fitting your device from there. This seems to be one possibility and surely my earlier solution was not on right lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We’re beginning to roll out Google Allo for Android and iOS, and the app will be available worldwide in the next few days.

(Taken from the end of the blog post)

Google roll out app releases in stages. Initially it will be available to a small percentage of devices and countries. Over a few days (or weeks even) it will roll out to more devices and countries.

Comment: So it's highly possible that it's just because they're still *deploying* the app. Gonna wait for a few more days and see what happens. Thanks!

Comment: So I just checked again and Google Allo is now available. Turns out it's just with the roll-out. Thanks! :)